# Using $0 to refer to entire match in Javascript's String.replace

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm highlighting instances of a search string within a set of text. I want to preserve the case of the original text while replacing a case-insensitive match of the query. Here's what I started with:

```
text.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), '<em>$1</em>');
```

In this case, I'd need to escape `query` to prevent parentheses from breaking the submatch, so I thought I'd try:

```
text.replace(new RegExp(query, 'ig'), '<em>$0</em>');
```

But `$0` doesn't seem to be used - all matched strings are replaced with $0. I did find an alternative, however:

```
text.replace(new RegExp(query, 'ig'), function(match) { return '<em>' + match + '</em>'; });
```

I'm not a huge fan of how this looks, though. How would you recommend doing this type of string replacement?

Comment: You probably need to escape metacharacters one way or the other.

Comment: I'd actually like to keep them :)

Comment: Unescaped user input into HTML = XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `$&` and not `$0` to refer to the entire match. I blame Perl.

Answer (score 1):

use $$0 instead of $0

```
str.replace(/\$/,'$$')
```

Comment: This should be str.replace(/\$/,'$$$$') since '$$' means '$'.