# Using exec to find multiple matches fails when we are trying to replace with the match itself

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the sequence **ab** with a **red ab**. The example is taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec. The problem I face is that when I use as replacement the **${myArray[0]}** it fails while it works when I use as replacement the "**XX**", for example. Any idea anyone why it does not work? Any other recommendation is welcome. Thank you all in advance.

**Some extra help for the community**: The answer given is connected with [Using $0 to refer to entire match in Javascript's String.replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002334/using-0-to-refer-to-entire-match-in-javascripts-string-replace). There, user166390 proposes **$& instead of $0**. And then it works fine !!!

```
<div id="Demonstration"></div>

<script>
// INPUT
// abbcdefabh
// WANTED OUTPUT
// XXcdefXXh

    let myRe = /ab*/g;
    let str = 'abbcdefabh';
    let myArray;
    while ((myArray = myRe.exec(str)) !== null) {
// IT WORKS !!!
        str = str.replace(`${myArray[0]}`, "XX");
// IT DOES NOT WORK !!!
        str = str.replace(`${myArray[0]}`, `<span style = "color:red;">${myArray[0]}</span>`);
    }
    document.getElementById('Demonstration').innerHTML = str;
</script>
```

Comment: "*I would like to run it with the exec() function*" - but why? It definitely is the wrong approach. If you really want to do that, you need to replace by using string operations with indices and lengths, not by using `replace`. And you need to adjust the `myRe.lastIndex` manually after altering the `str`.

Comment: Just write `innerHTML = str.replace(myRe, '<span style = "color:red;">$0</span>');` and be done. No `exec`, no looping.

Comment: Do you understand *why* it does not work?

Comment: Dear Bergi, thank you a lot for your time and interest. Although it is not very clear to me, the key word of yours is that I need to adjust the myRe.lastIndex. On the other hand in the solution you proposed it is not clear what is this "$0". I shall search about it also. But what I would like to suggest is to make your comments an answer so as to vote for it positively and your reccomendations to become useful to the community. Although I do not understand it thoroughly, it is an answer that it is worth of voting with value added. it is a pitty not to do it. Anyway, thank you again a lot.

Comment: I didn't make it an answer as you explicitly asked for "*please do not propose some other way in doing that*" :-) Can you clarify your requirements maybe?

Comment: I shall correct the question, in order you to do it. Tnx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I face is that when I use as replacement the `${myArray[0]}` it fails

That's because you are changing the string while searching it. You are keeping the `ab*` occurrences and since their positions changed, the search will continue to match them and the string grows forever. Try debugging with a breakpoint in the loop and watch the `str` and `myRe.lastIndex`/`myArray.index` expressions.

> I would like to try it exclusively with the `exec()`.

Don't. The proper tool for this job is just `replace`, with a [replacer string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter):

```
….innerHTML = str.replace(myRe, '<span style = "color:red;">$0</span>');
```